# Ebeans validation strange behaviour with custom message

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, ebean

I`ve got simple validation like:

```
@Column(length=6)
@Pattern(regexp = "[0-9]{2}( |-)?[0-9]{3}", message = Errors.kod_pocztowy)
private String kod_pocztowy;
```

But it return strange errors:

```
failed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/el/ELContext
[error]     at org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.interpolateExpression(ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.java:227)
[error]     at org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.interpolateMessage(ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.java:187)
[error]     at org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.interpolate(ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.java:115)
[error]     at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidationContext.interpolate(ValidationContext.java:370)
[error]     at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidationContext.createConstraintViolation(ValidationContext.java:284)
[error]     at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidationContext.createConstraintViolations(ValidationContext.java:246)
[error]     at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateSingleConstraint(ConstraintTree.java:289)
[error]     at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:133)
[error]     at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:91)
[error]     at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core.MetaConstraint.validateConstraint(MetaConstraint.java:85)
[error]     at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:478)
[error]     at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForDefaultGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:424)
[error]     at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForCurrentGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:388)
[error]     at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateInContext(ValidatorImpl.java:340)
[error]     at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validate(ValidatorImpl.java:158)
```

When i`m changing message property to text like:

```
@Column(length=6)
@Pattern(regexp = "[0-9]{2}( |-)?[0-9]{3}", message = "Now its ok")
private String kod_pocztowy;
```

Then everything seems to be ok. What`s the problem ? Anyone can explain it for me?

Comment: Ok, i`ve found it by myself. Using chars like {} causes Ebean to load message from class and this message is related to that class.

Comment: You should create an answer to this question with your solution, and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i`ve found it by myself. Using chars like {} causes Ebean to load message from class and this message is related to that class.